# GPS/GSM Tracker not sending location

Tags: communication, gsm, mobile-data, gps, tracking-devices

I bought GPS/GSM Tracker from eBay but it doesn't work and i can't get Location

**Steps I followed:**

I bought a new sim card with calls and data (checked that it working)

I installed an app on my phone that connecting to the Tracker's server

The app configuration included IMEI Number and Cellphone Number

I was able to make calls to the Tracker and have heard its surroundings but I can't get a location or send other commands.

I tested the sim card on my phone (Samsung S5 with LinageOS) with various of data configuration as following: GSM only (E), WCDMA Only (H+), LTE (LTE).

**Questions:**

- Does someone encounter a similar issue with those devices?
- Does it have some configuration interface using SMS? or other protocols like WEP?
- Do I have to configure APN? because there is no information about
  APN configuration in the manual.

**More info, links and images:**

The app is an apk file (not in play store) name BabyCaring: http://manage.5gcity.com/app/

It's a Chinese product without a brand or model from eBay - "Pet Dogs Cats Sheep Finder Realtime GPS/GSM Tracker Waterproof For Android iOS" 
[image: The product I'm using - GPS Tracker For Dog]

[Ebay Link](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Pet-Dogs-Cats-Sheep-Finder-Realtime-GPS-GSM-Tracker-Waterproof-For-Android-iOS/392097084010?hash=item5b4aceb26a%3Am%3AmVBrU0r7rZz7nyTdSZS2RlA&var=661043181839)

The product use MTK2503D GPS/GSM chip

[image: MTK2503D GPS/GSM chip]

Similar Product from the same company - Children’s Phone Wear (BabyCaring) CY72
[image: Children’s Phone Wear (BabyCaring) CY72]
http://manage.5gcity.com/manual/cy72/CY72_LBS_122_ENG.htm

They have two more older models:
http://manage.5gcity.com/manual/cy19/CY19D_144_ENG.files/image002.jpg
http://manage.5gcity.com/manual/cy19/CY19_LBS_ENG.files/image002.jpg

Thank you very much,
Or Hirshfeld

Comment: why did you post this? .... do you have a specific question? .... are you trying to advertise the products here?

Comment: I really don't try to advertise the product, I actually really hate this product right now and doesn't recommend it at all.
Sorry if wasn't clear, English is not my mother tongue.  I edited my post so i hope now it would be clear. I would appricate to get your feedback, thank you.

Comment: if you cannot get the GPS information from the device and the GPS function is advertised as being functional, then contact the company that sold the product ... it appears that the device is defective

Comment: Most likely a defective product, with unknown customer support. I don't think we can help with this type of problem. Sure, the GSM/GPS ship is relevant, but there are too many unknowns.

Comment: I thought maybe someone encounters the same product or have some experience with MTK2503D, maybe this chip have configuration method through SMS or something similar

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same device which isn't working either.

Comment: @stuartb no I gave up, shity product, next time I would but product with a real company behind